# Why release contains AppName.exe.config?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I used to create release of my application developped by Visual Studio 2012. Then I deleted .pdb files and AppName.vshost.exe. So I had as result AppName.exe + .dll and the .exe run as exepected.

But recently when I have created a release, I found:

- AppName.exe
- .pdb files
- AppName.vshost.exe
- .dll
- **AppName.exe.config**

and if I delete AppName.exe.config, my application doesn't work !!

*My question is:*
why AppName.config.exe appreared  suddently ? How can I create release without this file.

Comment: Have you looked in it? My guess it that it contains bindingRedirect or something similar that you need to redirect to a specific assembly version.

Comment: I open it. Yes you are right. it contains <assemblyBinding> </assemblyBinding> which redirect a specific assembly. It's strange. "How can I correct this ?" and to more understand your guess, I have another question please: I find many other statements in .exe.config like userSettings, configSections... "is the apparition of .exe.config is caused only by bindingRedirect  or also the other statemnt can cause this ? "

Comment: That is usually caused by other dependecies that want different versions (i.e. dependency A wants version 1.0 of dependency C while dependency B wants 1.1. Since you can't have different versions loaded Visual Studio (or possibly nuget) adds a redirect for the older version to use the new one instead. If you remove the redirect then dependency A will say it can't find the correct version anymore. You can try updating your dependencies, but unless they have fixed this (which they might not have) you just got to keep your .exe.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should not delete the config file, as its name the file contains some basic configuration like .Net Framework version and so on and can contain some useful information about your application that can be changed in a text editor and change your application by the way.
for example if you add something in Properties > Settings it will add something like this to your config file:

```
    <userSettings>
    <TestWinApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="myUserSetting1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>123</value>
        </setting>
    </TestWinApp.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
<applicationSettings>
    <TestWinApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="myAppSetting1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>456</value>
        </setting>
    </TestWinApp.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Comment: I completely agree with you, but I can't understand why in all my release I delivred the .config doens't exist in the release folder and the app run as expected !!

Comment: could you please open the file in a text editor and try to find some new config you may made in your application and the VS placed it in the config file.

Comment: there should be some information that the executable is looking for at run-time.

Comment: <assemblyBinding> </assemblyBinding> is the new config placed in my app

Comment: As far as I understand it, we can use the bindingRedirect to make the app load a newer or older version of an assembly in case the version we were using when compiling the EXE has become too old.